# Mysterious ClasscastException from apache httpclient code

Tags: java, apache, exception, classcastexception

We are using Apache's commons-httpclient-3.1 library in our project. However, due to legacy and other project specific dependencies we are not using any of the implementations of the SecureProtocolSocketFactory interface provided by Apache (like SSLProtocolSocketFactory,StrictSSLProtocolSocketFactory) We have created our own SocketFactory called HttpClient3xSocketFactory which implements SecureProtocolSocketFactory interface.This factory is registered with Apache by calling the Protocol.registerProtocol method of org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.Protocol.java. Given below snippet of our code

```
public class HttpClient3xSocketFactory implements SecureProtocolSocketFactory {
. . .

private static final ProtocolSocketFactory socketFactory = new HttpClient3xSocketFactory();
private static final Protocol httpsProto = new Protocol("https",
        socketFactory, 443);
```

And registered like below

```
Protocol.registerProtocol("https", httpsProto);
```

However this generates a mysterious ClasscastException from tunnelCreated() method of Apache's HttpConnection from the last line

```
 if (usingSecureSocket) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Already using a secure socket");
    }
 if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
        LOG.debug("Secure tunnel to " + this.hostName + ":" + this.portNumber);
    }
 SecureProtocolSocketFactory socketFactory =
        (SecureProtocolSocketFactory) protocolInUse.getSocketFactory();
```

The exception says --

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.vmware.vdi.common.saml.HttpClient3xSocketFactory cannot be cast to org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.SecureProtocolSocketFactory
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.tunnelCreated(HttpConnection.java:791)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeConnect(HttpMethodDirector.java:528)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:404)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:178)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:408)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:327)
```

But com.vmware.vdi.common.saml.HttpClient3xSocketFactory DOES implement org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.SecureProtocolSocketFactory interface. Have verified using GetClassLoader method that both are loaded using the same class loader. Also used reflection at run time to check that com.vmware.vdi.common.saml.HttpClient3xSocketFactory actually does implement org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.SecureProtocolSocketFactory interface. So I am at a loss to understand as to why the ClassCaseException is generated.